# Installing a second instance of Bash (with different config)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, rpm

I have repackaged a Bash RPM to include automatic logging to syslog.  I am trying to work out a way to set this up so that it is used ONLY when a user or service account runs a command as root.  The option I'm looking at is installing this version of Bash to an alternate location, and then pointing root to use that version as it's default shell.

Can someone go through the process of installing this RPM to an alternate path and associating the root account to it as the default shell?  I have been having difficulty finding a way to do this when searching online.

Comment: Have you looked at trying to achieve this using commands in `.bashrc` for `root`?

Comment: Yes!  I'm looking into both methods.  However I am a little confused on the command structure on what would go into .bashrc.  I found an article on it, but it wasn't terribly clear.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are repackaging the RPM, it is probably best to change the destination path directly in the RPM.

As for the default shell, run `chsh -s /path/to/your/bash root` to change it.

Be aware that this solution may not work for all purposes though. For example, running a script that starts with `#!/bin/bash` will still execute it with `/bin/bash` instead of your default login shell.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm spinning up a fresh VM to test the altered configs.  But I'm not sure if I have all the locations that need to be changed.  I know the config-top.h file, but if you happen to know other file that will need to be altered, that would be a great help.  Thanks!